# Investgate the effect of insertAfter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

To understand the effect of [.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/), I designed a small table test that has 2 rows and 2 columns.

```
 <table id="myTable" width="560" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
        <tr>
          <td title="row 1*1" class="styletest">1*1</td>
          <td title="row 1*2" class="styletest">1*2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td title="row 2*1" class="styletest">2*1</td>
          <td title="row 2*2" class="styletest">2*2</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
```

The jquery code is:

```
var $tooltip = $('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
$tooltip.insertAfter('#myTable').hide();//I want to know the code after inserting this element.

function showTooltip(cell) {
    $tooltip.show().text(cell.attr("title"));
}
$('.styletest').hover(function() {
    showTooltip($(this));
 }, function() {
    $tooltip.hide();
 });
```

The test includes hovering different cells and display tooltips.
The demo is at [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/twPZA/1/)

I want to know the source code when I hover different cells.
For example, when I hover row 1, column 1, the snapshot likes:
[image: row1col1]
When I hover row 2, column 2, the snapshot likes:
[image: row2col2]

Questions:
When mouse hovers row 1 column1 and row 2 column 2;

1. Do they have the same rendered source code?(Using F12 can't get the rendered code when hovering)
2. Why the tooltips are displayed in the same position that seems in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same element, you are just changing it's content and visibilty. It's not going to move, and other than the content you are setting with  `text()` the markup is not going to change either.

You don't need to inspect anything, the source code is right there in your script, and what you insert is what you get, so to speak!

Comment: Why the tooltips are in the same position even I hover different cells?

Comment: @Love: I recommend to just insert the `div` with some content and use, for example, Chrome's Developer Tools to inspect the DOM. This will show you the dimensions of each element. For example, I assume that the `div` spreads over the whole width of the page and it's content is centered. Why should the position of the content change when you hover over an other cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect styles on elements that only apply on `hover` in firebug:

Inspect the element that has a hover style, click on the DOM node so it's selected and highlighted in blue. Then go to the style tab on the right and click the little arrow, and choose `:hover` now Firefox will hold the hover styles and you can insect the div at the bottom.

[image]

In your case, either you have CSS for `#tooltip` or styles for divs to have text centered.